# Is there a way to run NameSpace.SendAndReceive() from Redemption? Without opening the Outlook Object Model?

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am using a WPF app to loop through appointments and do some processing. If Outlook is not open, sometimes the calendar is not up to date. So, I'm running this method:

```
 private void SendAndReceive()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OutlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace mapiNameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        ns.SendAndReceive(false);
        if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(OutlookApp);
        if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mapiNameSpace);
        if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
    }
```

This works fine however I don't want Outlook to open. It's visible on the system tray for a few moments and disappears.

Wondering if there's a way to accomplish the same thing using Redemption?
If you could also provide a sample bit of code, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do - Microsoft removed MAPI spooler from Outlook 2002, so `MAPIUtils.DeliverNow` has not worked ever since, and it is not even exposed by (newer) `RDOSession` object.

The only workarounds are listed at https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#1

Comment: Thanks! I just ended up using the SendAndReceive function above and letting it run periodically(once and hour). Running it too much though seemed to cause Outlook to throw an error - "outlook has consumed all resources".